# Pasar array como parámetro en web service - NuSoap

Tags: webservice

Desde mi controlador en laravel, estoy ejecutando el llamado al cliente de un web service enviando dos parámetros en el, ambos son array. Ahora, en el cliente los recibo normal y de igual manera desde este mismo hago el llamado al servicio del servidor donde en el register (`$servicio->register()`) debo hacer el llamado a la función del lado servidor, pero no sé como enviar los parámetros en el register siendo estos dos tipo array.
Dejaré mi código:

Controlador:

```
$encabezado = array(posiciones y valores del array);
$detalle = array(posiciones y valores del array);
$respuesta = llenarPropiedadesMovimiento($encabezado, $detalle);
```

Cliente:

```
include_once public_path().'/nusoap/nusoap.php';
$cliente = new nusoap_client('urldelservidor', false);
$parametros = array('encabezado' => $encabezado, 'detalle' => $detalle);

$respuesta = $cliente->call('llenarPropiedadesMovimiento', $parametros);
return $respuesta;
```

Servidor:

```
include_once 'nusoap/nusoap.php';

$servicio = new soap_server();
$ns = "urn:miserviciowsdl"; 
$servicio->configureWSDL("Documento Comercial",$ns);
$servicio->schemaTargetNamespace = $ns;

#Metodo register que recibe 4 parametros
#Parametro 1 nombre de la función
#Parametro 2 parametros de entrada que recibe la función y que tipo de campo es 
#Parametro 3 lo que voy a retornar (string, int, xml)
#Parametro 4 el namespace

$servicio->register("llenarPropiedadesMovimiento", array('encabezado' => 'xsd:array', 'detalle' => 'xsd:array'), array('return' => 'xsd:string'), $ns );

function llenarPropiedadesMovimiento($encabezado, $detalle) 
{
    require_once('clase.class.php'); 

    $interfacedatos = new FichaTecnica();
    $interface = $interfacedatos->llenarPropiedadesMovimiento($encabezado, $detalle);

    return $interface;
}


$HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA = isset($HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA) ? $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA : ''; 
$servicio->service($HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA);
```

Nuevamente... En el parámetro 2, en el archivo del servidor, ¿Cómo envío el encabezado y el detalle siendo estos array?

Answer (score 0):

Dando respuesta a mi pregunta, me faltaba configurar esto en el lado servidor

```
#Configuramos el array para el encabezado
$servicio->wsdl->addComplexType('encabezado', 'complexType', 'struct', 'all', '',
array(
'idMovimiento' => array('idMovimiento' => 'idMovimiento', 'type' => 'xsd:int'),
'Movimiento_idMovimiento' => array('Movimiento_idMovimiento' => 'Movimiento_idMovimiento', 'type' => 'xsd:int'))
);

#Configuramos el array para el detalle
$servicio->wsdl->addComplexType('detalle', 'complexType', 'struct', 'all', '', 
array(
'idMovimientoDetalle' => array('idMovimientoDetalle' => 'idMovimientoDetalle', 'type' => 'xsd:int'),
'Producto_idProducto' => array('Producto_idProducto' => 'Producto_idProducto', 'type' => 'xsd:int'))
);

$servicio->register("llenarPropiedadesMovimiento", array('encabezado' => 'tns:encabezado', 'detalle' => 'tns:detalle'), array('return' => 'xsd:string'), $ns );
```